# React, unexpected token '-'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Here's what I get when I try to compile using webpack:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                         13:25:46

 error  in ./resources/assets/react/components/Navigation/Navbar.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (100:13)

   98 |         }
   99 |         className = "disabled dropdown-toggle"
> 100 |         data - toggle = "dropdown"
      |              ^
  101 |         role = "button"
  102 |         aria - expanded = "false" > Jobs < /a> <
  103 |         /li> <



 @ ./resources/assets/react/components/Navigation/Navigation.js 41:14-33
 @ multi ./resources/assets/react/components/Navigation/Navigation.js
```

Here's my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "0.16.2",
        "babel-preset-es2017": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
        "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
        "babel-core": "6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "1.0.2",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self": "6.22.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "6.22.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
```

and my babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "env", "stage-0"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "dynamic-import-node",
        "syntax-dynamic-import",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-jsx",
        "transform-react-jsx-self",
        "transform-react-jsx-source",
        "transform-regenerator",
        "transform-runtime"
    ],
    "comments": true
}
```

What else do I need to make it to work?  I am trying to make it to work, however I don't know what plugin or preset is missing in order for it to understand what '-' is supposed to do

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import NavbarDropdown from './NavbarDropdown'

const Sidebar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`sidebar ${props.open && 'open'}`} role="navigation" style={{ display: props.open && 'block' }}>
      <nav ref={props.setWrapperRef}>
        <h3 id="nav-title">Menu</h3>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><img id="nav-logo" src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/liveandnow-production/public/images/liveOldham.png" alt="LiveOldham" /></li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/entity">People &amp; Places</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/events">Events</a>
          </li>
          <hr className="nav-rule" />
          <NavbarDropdown label="Travel">
            <li>
              <a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/travel/tram">Tram</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Bus</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Train</a>
            </li>
          </NavbarDropdown>
          <NavbarDropdown label="News">
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Chronicle</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">M.E.N.</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Rochdale Observer</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Middleton Guardian</a>
            </li>
          </NavbarDropdown>
          <NavbarDropdown label="Entertainment">
            <li>
              <a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/cinema/all">Cinema</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Theatre</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="disabled" href="">Gigs</a>
            </li>
          </NavbarDropdown>
          <li className="dropdown">
            <a href="" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()} className="disabled dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Jobs</a>
          </li>
          <li className="dropdown">
            <a href="" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()} className="disabled dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Properties</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="footer">
          <div className="footer-links copyright">
            <p>Copyright© Live &amp; Now Limited - 2017</p>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
              |
              <li><a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/terms">Terms</a></li>
              |
              <li><a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
              |
              <li><a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/cookies">Cookie</a></li>
              |
              <li><a href="https://app.liveoldham.com/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="social-links">
            <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.facebook.com/liveoldham/" target="_blank"><i className="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://twitter.com/live_oldham" target="_blank"><i className="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/live_oldham/" target="_blank"><i className="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Here is my Navbar.js so that you can see what is actually happening

Comment: JSX may give the impression that it is markup, but is actually translated to JS code. Each "attribute" is actually translated to an object property. Object properties with a dash are not allowed in JS - the problem is this "attribute" `data-toggle="dropdown"`. See [some](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1259) [related](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1134) [issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Whatever React limitations may be, it does not explain this as a parse-time error.

Comment: There appears to be whitespace around your dashes, e.g. `data - toggle` instead of `data-toggle`. The error looks more like ESLint than Babel, so my guess would be something else you've installed is autoformatting your code and injecting whitespace around the JSX identifiers causing them to break.

Comment: This isn't a problem with React, `data - toggle` is not a valid DOM attribute, but `data-toggle` is.